# Finding the area of a surface (involves curves that are defined using polar coordinates)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

> Set $D$ is bounded by the lines $y=0,x=0$ and by the curve (in polar coordinates) $r(\theta)=e^{\theta}, 0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. 
> We define $Q=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: (x,y)\in\partial D, 0 \le z \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \}$. Find the area of $Q$. 
> Note: $\partial D$ is boundary of $D$.

I'm having a difficult time deciding what to do in this question, having the curve in polar coordinates is very confusing. 
If I want to move to polar coordinates: $x=pcos(t), y=psin(t)$, then what about the curve $r(\theta)$? 
I'm really stuck here and I would appreciate any help. 
Thanks in advance! 
**Edit (Attempt after help of Math Lover):**
$x=e^{\theta}\cos(\theta), y=e^{\theta}\sin(\theta), z=z$. 
Finding the bounds: 
$0\le z\le\sqrt{e^{2\theta}cos^2\theta+e^{2\theta}sin^2\theta}=e^{\theta}$. 
$e^{\theta}cos\theta=0 \Longrightarrow \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ 
$e^{\theta}sin\theta=0 \Longrightarrow \theta=0.$ 
(Was this necessary? I got the same bounds for $\theta$). 

Now I know that in order to find area of a surface, I need to have the "upper" curve, which is $z=e^{\theta}=f(x(\theta),y(\theta))$.
So, a vector that draws my curve: 
$\vec l=(e^{\theta}cos\theta, e^{\theta}sin\theta, z), 0 \le z \le e^{\theta}. 0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$. 
But here I got stuck, otherwise I'll get a double integral, I'm thinking of why can I remove $z$ or why not.
Completing the solution: 
$\vec l = (e^{\theta}cos\theta, e^{\theta}sin\theta)$ 
$d\vec l = (-e^{\theta}sin\theta + e^{\theta}cos\theta, e^{\theta}cos\theta + e^{\theta}sin\theta)$. 
$|d\vec l| = \sqrt{(-e^{\theta}sin\theta + e^{\theta}cos\theta)^2+( e^{\theta}cos\theta + e^{\theta}sin\theta))^2}=\sqrt{e^{2\theta}-e^{2\theta}sin(2\theta) + e^{2\theta}+e^{2\theta}sin(2\theta)}=\sqrt{2}e^{\theta}$ (Yay!) 
$$\int_{l}fdl=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{\theta}\sqrt{2}e^{\theta}d\theta = \sqrt{2}[\frac{e^{\pi}}{2}-\frac{e^0}{2}]$$

Comment: Please note $\partial D$ is boundary of $D$. So please parametrize similar to how you would do it for lateral surface of a cylinder. Find $|r'(\theta, z)|$ and then integrate.

Comment: @MathLover fixed the boundary (I just didn't know how to translate it), I don't understand what you mean about the bound of $z$, I don't see where it moved after the text. I still don't get how it's normal parametrization, lets say I take $x=r\cos(t),y=r\sin(t),z=z$. What is $r(\theta)$? how can I link it with my parametrization, I've never dealt with anything like this before, what's more bothering me is I can't see or visualize what I'm doing.

Comment: $x = e^{\theta} \cos \theta, y = ..., z = z$.

Comment: of course you can visualize. Go to desmos and type $r = e^{\theta}$. You get a $2$D graph. Now the distance from the origin to a point on the curve $(r = e^{\theta})$ is the upper bound of $z$ at that point. In other words, it is a cylinder with boundary as $r(\theta)$ and the height changes according to radius at any given point.

Comment: @MathLover I'm having a hard time understanding $r(\theta)$ curve, I don't get why the graph looks like it does in desmos, I'm missing something for sure. Why you substituted $r(\theta)$ instead of the radius like we usually do in $rcos(\theta)$. is this bonus curve just telling me that I have the $r$ as a function of $\theta$ whenever I wanna use polar coordinates? but I can't see where it tells me that in the question..

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I can understand that part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126560/discussion-between-math-lover-and-pwaol).